# Call javascript from mvc dropdownlistfor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

This has been asked and answered before, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. How should I call a javascript function from an Html.DropDownListFor control in .Net MVC?

This is what I thought should work (on a partial view):

```
@model MySite.CultureViewModel

<script language="text/javascript">

    function ChangeCulture() {
        alert("please work");
    };
</script>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLanguageId, Model.LanguageSelector, new { onchange = "ChangeCulture();" })
}
```

What am I doing wring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Razor code is fine. The problem is `<script language="text/javascript">`...

It should be `<script type="text/javascript">` or `<script language="javascript">` (deprecated)

Comment: Arrggghh, how stupid am I?! Thank you so much for spotting this!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget extra "@":

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLanguageId, Model.LanguageSelector, new { @onchange = "ChangeCulture();" })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.NameID, Model.MyList, new { id = "hi" });


    $("#hi").click(function(){
    alert("Hello");
})
```